# Programmatically evaluate JSONPath Expression in Java

Tags: java, rest, jsonpath

I’m building up a middleware RestAPI which communicates with a SOAP backend.

As the BE requires certain attributes for the Operation I would like to pass them via JSON path to the Rest API and the Spring Boot Microservice should be able to translate it to the Backend’s language.

Example:

```
filter=product[?(@.creationDate>=‘2020-10-01’ && @.name == ‘someName’)]
```

The Backend has some raw filtering mechanisms, but I need to somehow translate this / extract the Operator / left and right node.

By accessing it I mean

`@.creationDate>=‘2020-10-01’`

Left node == `@.creationDate`

Operator == `>=`

Right Node == ‘2020-10-01’

When I use jayway JSONPath I can use the filter compiler and can compile that JSONPath Expression.

Example Compile

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.Filter;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.filter.FilterCompiler;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
public class JsonPathTest {

  @Test
  void testJsonPath(){
    Filter filter= FilterCompiler.compile(" [?(@.status=='Pending' && @.@type=='Document')]");


  }
}
```

[image: Debug result]

But I can’t access the compiled result in a way where I can simply iterate through each expression.

Any help is highly appreciated.

BR

Comment: what is mean by this  I need to somehow translate this / extract the Operator / left and right node.?

Comment: `@.creationDate>=‘2020-10-01’`

Left node == `@.creationDate`

Operator == `>=`

Right Node == ‘2020-10-01’

Comment: please share your code which compile?

Comment: Added in original post.